# Bit shift result differs in PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, bit-shift

I try convert some PHP code to C#. Could you tell me why this returns dfferent values?

```
(1 << 56) | (1 << 52) | (1 << 32) | (97448965 << 1) | 1
```

PHP returned value:

```
76561198155163659
```

C#:

```
UInt64 s64 = (1 << 56) | (1 << 52) | (1 << 32) | (97448965 << 1) | 1;
//194897931
```

Bit shift results

```
Bit shift     | C#       | PHP
--------------|----------| -----------------
1 << 56       |16777216  | 72057594037927936 
1 << 52       |1048576   | 4503599627370496 
1 << 32       |1         | 4294967296 
97448965 << 1 |194897930 | 194897930
```

Comment: edited, added table

Comment: I think that C# is treating those 1 literals as 32 bit integers and is treating the left shift operator as a rotate left operator (hence why 1 << 32 = 1).  Try replacing the 1 literals with 1L or 1LL (that means long int or long long int respectively in C++) or writing out explicit casts to 64 bit int.

Comment: I replaced the 1 literals with 1L and now it works. Thank you.